# Initialize extended struct in c++

Tags: c++

I'm having some problem initializing an extended struct in c++.

```
struct Struct1 {
  int property1;
}
struct Struct2: Struct1 {
  int property2;
}

int main() {
  Struct2 struct_var = { 1, 1 };
  std::cout << struct_var.property1;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could point out what is wrong?

Comment: Struct2 is not an aggregate and cannot be initialized with aggregate-initialization.

Comment: How do I initialize Struct2 then? I thought it inherits everything from Struct1 and you can do a `{..}`?

Comment: well - even `einstein` doesn't know it!

Comment: @billz I'm a physicist not a programmer.

Comment: god does not play aggregate initialization

Comment: To enable `{1 ,1}` as initializer you could use *containment* instead: `struct Struct2 { Struct1 s1; int property2; }`

Comment: Everything is relative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you pass `2 arguments` in initializer, then you need to have constructor which have `2 parameters`. something like this

```
#include <iostream>

struct Struct1 {
    int property1;
};
struct Struct2 : Struct1 {
public:
    Struct2(int property1, int property2)
    {
        // Struct1::property1 = property1; // this will also work
        this->property1 = property1;
        this->property2 = property2;
    }
    int property2;
};
int main() {
    Struct2 struct_var = { 1, 1 };
    std::cout << struct_var.property1;
}
```